# Android How can i easily read and add to the List data from txt file?

Tags: java, android, file, loaddata

My code: https://pastebin.com/KudWYD8W

I don't know how write method loadData.
I wanna have list with only names of Games and when I press on the element should show the details.
My file looks like:

Witcher

1996

free

66h

Please help. I tried in many ways but there was always something wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this.

1.Save the string to be read as different list item separated with a `comma(,)`.

2.Call this method to get the list by passing the file path.

```
private List<String> populateAutoComplete(String path)
    {
        try
        {
            String content = readFile(path);
            Log.d(TAG,
                  "populateAutoComplete: " + content);
            List<String> listToPopulate = Arrays.asList(content.split("\\s*,\\s*"));
            return listToPopulate;
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return Collections.emptyList();
        }
    }
```

Ask in case of any doubts. Cheers :)